# Не передается let-переменная js в переменную php методом POST в форме

Tags: javascript, php

Есть форма, которой нужно передать в php значения переменных var и let. Переменные var передаются без проблем, а let не хотят. Подскажите решение, пожалуйста.

Проблемные переменные - let price и let prodname.

Всем спасибо за ответ.

```js
var klishe = 0,
  times = 1,
  osnastka = 0,
  shipp = 0;

jQuery("#modal_form-c .add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
  let price = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".price").text();
  klishe = price.match(/\d+/);
  jQuery("#ott-price").text(price);
  let prodname = jQuery(this).closest('ul').find(".title").text();
  jQuery("#ott-name").text(prodname);
});
```

Часть кода обработчика формы -

```php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

//передаются без проблем
$ogrn = htmlspecialchars($_POST["ogrn"]);
$inn = htmlspecialchars($_POST["inn"]);

// эти переменные let не передаются 

$prodname = $_POST['prodname'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

// эти переменные var передаются без проблем
$times = $_POST['times'];
$shipp = $_POST['shipp'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Плохо, конечно, что нет html, но я догадываюсь в чем дело. Вы показываете эти переменные на странице как `innerText` каких-то элементов, `div`, `p` или `span`. На сервер при отправке формы посылаются только значения элементов пользовательского ввода - `input`, `select`, `textarea`.

Добавьте это в разметку формы:

```
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" />
```

а это в код:

```
jQuery("#ott-price").text(price);
jQuery("#price").val(price);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, хочу отправить текстовое значение из html. А как можно решить проблему?

Comment: @Максим Как Вы отправляете данные - submit-ом формы или ajax-ом?

Comment: case 'goToNewPage':
                        jQuery.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: jQueryform.attr('action'),
                                data: jQueryform.serialize(),
                            })